# Function signature for high order function

Tags: c++, templates

When defining a template function taking a function as parameter, what is the difference between taking the function parameter by value and by universal reference ?
(i.e) :

```
template <typename Fn,typename... Args>
void apply(Fn&& fn, Args &&... args);
```

and

```
template <typename Fn,typename... Args>
void apply(Fn fn, Args &&... args);
```

Or maybe the question is : should the function template parameter be an universal reference to maximize genericity ?  Or give example where both signature would give different behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

If you only pass functions, I believe there's little difference. In both cases, function will be first converted to function pointers.

If you're to pass a [*FunctionObject*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject), like a lambda or `std::function`, things will become different. There'll be a copy if call by value. Sometimes maybe it's not what you expect.
e.g.

```cpp
struct Callable {
    ...
    Callable(const& Callable); // maybe expensive to copy
    void operator()();
};

template <typename Fn,typename... Args>
void apply_v(Fn fn, Args &&... args);


template <typename Fn,typename... Args>
void apply_ur(Fn&& fn, Args &&... args);

Callable c;
// do something to c
apply_v(c); // may be less effective
apply_ur(c);
apply_ur(std::move(c));
```

But it really depends on your situation, I believe.

Maybe you can take a look at the signiture in STL, it seems they tend to take a universal reference.

e.g. [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
template< class F, class... Args >
constexpr /*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

or construtor of [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Most general considerations for type of arguments apply to passing callables as well. I refer you to the core guidelines https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing.

> Or give example where both signature would give different behaviour.

Consider that `operator()` can be overloaded based on l/r-valueness:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    void operator()() const & { std::cout << "hello "; }
    void operator()() && { std::cout << "world\n";}
};

template <typename F> void apply1(F&& f) { std::forward<F>(f)(); }
template <typename F> void apply2(F f) { f(); }


int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cout << "apply1\n";
    apply1(f);
    apply1(foo{});
    std::cout << "apply2\n";
    apply2(f);
    apply2(foo{});
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/M1xKq6zsc):

```
apply1
hello world
apply2
hello hello
```